# Adding timer to count time UIButton pressed iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, nstimer

How can I add timer to detect how much time UIButton was pressed on iPhone?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need a timer for that. Just a simple variable to increment number of taps.

Comment: I think no.. I just want to show user how long button was pressed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare buttonPressedStartTime as a CFTimeInterval in your .h file.

When the button is pressed, store the current time:

```
buttonPressedStartTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
```

When the users thouches up the binger,

```
float deltaTimeInSeconds = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - buttonPressedStartTime;
```

Comment: sorry, my fault =) Working nice! =)

Answer (score 1):

```
 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
      //Check here for touch is in your button frame than add
     [self performSelector:@selector(judgeLongPresstime) withObject:nil afterDelay:YourDelayTimeCheck];
 }

 - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
     [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestWithTarget:self];
 }

 -(void)judgeLongPresstime
 {
      //Add timer here and get time of increaseing.
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for response. But this is not what I want. I don't need count of buttons click. If user touch the button and holding it, so I need time how much he's holding.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// somewhere in interface
NSDate *_startDate;


- (IBAction)buttonDown:(id)sender {
    _startDate = [[NSDate date] retain];
}


- (IBAction)buttonUp:(id)sender {
    NSTimeInterval pressedForInSeconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] - [startDate timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSLog(@"button was pressed for: %d seconds", pressedForInSeconds);
    [_startDate release];
}
```

Then wire `buttonDown:` action to "Touch down inside" outlet, and `buttonUp:` to "Touch up inside" or "Touch up outside" outlet in button connections tab in Interface Builder.

Comment: Should be `NSTimeInterval pressedForInSeconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] - [startDate timeIntervalSince1970];`

Comment: Thanks @allenlinli. Code sample is fixed.